# Redirect the JSON response to another html page (Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, session-storage

I just recently started using Angular, and I am trying to redirect the response of http.get to another html page which is `result.html`. I used services to share data:

Here is my controller code:

```
  app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http, $window, sharedProperties){
  $scope.generate = function(){
    $http.get('repositories', {params: { username : $scope.username }}).
    then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.error = "";
      sharedProperties.setData(response.data);
      $window.location.href = '/result.html';
    }, function myError() {
      $scope.error = "Wrong Username";
    });
  }
});

app.controller("resultController", function($scope, $window,sharedProperties){
  $scope.names = sharedProperties.getData();
  $scope.home = function() {
    $window.location.href = '/index.html';
  }
  });
```

Here is the `services.js` code:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var data;
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return data;
        },
        setData: function(value) {
            data = value;
        },
    }
});
```

Here is the `index.html` body:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="controller">
    <p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="username"  placeholder="Enter username here" required>
      <button ng-click="generate()">Generate</button>
    </p>

   {{ error }}
</div>
```

And here is the `result.html` that I want the response goes to:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="resultController">
    <p><button ng-click="home()">Home</button></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">
            {{ "Name: " + x.name + ", Languages: " + x.languages }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `controller` set the response data through `sharedProperties` so the `resultController` can use it, however after the page redirects to `result.html` the result is not shown.

**UPDATE**

It seems the data is not shared between the two controller, `console.log` shows `undefined`. Is it because of 2 different html files? or is it because of `redirect`?

**UPDATE 2**

I realized that redirect will reset all the data, so I use `sessionStorate` for the service:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function() {

    return {
        getData: function() {
            return sessionStorage.sharedProperties;
        },
        setData: function(value) {
           sessionStorage.sharedProperties = value;
        },
    }
});
```

however `console.log` instead of showing the values of json, it shows:

```
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

The real value is suppose to be:

```
[{"name":"git-consortium","languages":"No Language Reported"},{"name":"hello-worId","languages":"No Language Reported"},{"name":"Hello-World","languages":"No Language Reported"},{"name":"octocat.github.io","languages":"CSS JavaScript HTML "},{"name":"Spoon-Knife","languages":"CSS HTML "}]
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your angular project implementation totally wrong. Please read and learn about angular.js first. then if any questions appear ask here.  :)

Comment: please make sure your redirection route is defined properly sometime it'll redirect to default case..?

Comment: (1) You are giving the same name for both the controller.(2) You want to share data between two controllers, so use either services/factories, read it.(3) $window.location.href = 'result.html'; will redirect to result.html and once redirected the below expression  $scope.names = response.data; will not get executed.

Comment: but even if you want to implement in this way , you can use $rootScope.names=response.data and then redirect to result.html, just a trick , but it may have bad consequences.

Comment: thanks for your response @shreyansh

Comment: @shreyansh I updated the question with your suggestion, can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even Though the response that I was getting was json, I had to still convert to json using `angular.toJson()`.

Here is the service to save the json data:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.sharedProperties);
        },
        setData: function(value) {
           sessionStorage.sharedProperties = angular.toJson(value);
        },
    }
});
```

So now even after redirecting to another page, I can still access the data.